# Importing Vue Component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component registered with:

```
Vue.component('logo', function (resolve) {require(['./components/layout/Logo.vue'], resolve)});
```

The component itself is defined as:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="title">
            <a href="/">
                <h1>Welcome to my Site!</h1>
            </a>
        </div>
        <navigation></navigation>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
    h1 {
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-align: center;
        color: #000000;
    }

</style>

<script>
    import Navigation from './Navigation.vue';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                msg:'hello vue'
            }
        },
        components: {
            Navigation
        }
    }

</script>
```

`Logo.vue` and `Navigation.vue` are in the same directory. Webpack does not complain when running.

When the site loads though there is a console error reported:

```
app.js:142 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:50)
    at app.js:883
    at <anonymous>
__webpack_require__.oe @ app.js:142
Promise rejected (async)
(anonymous) @ app.js:883
resolveAsyncComponent @ app.js:33890
createComponent @ app.js:35368
_createElement @ app.js:35578
createElement @ app.js:35517
vm._c @ app.js:35857
(anonymous) @ VM449:2
Vue._render @ app.js:35909
updateComponent @ app.js:34319
get @ app.js:34662
Watcher @ app.js:34651
mountComponent @ app.js:34323
Vue$3.$mount @ app.js:39644
Vue$3.$mount @ app.js:41847
Vue._init @ app.js:36017
Vue$3 @ app.js:36102
(anonymous) @ app.js:886
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:50
(anonymous) @ app.js:857
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:50
(anonymous) @ app.js:145
(anonymous) @ app.js:148
app.js:50 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:50)
    at app.js:883
    at <anonymous>
```

The same error occurs when I register the second component globally with `Vue.component('navigation', function (resolve) {require(['./components/layout/Navigation.vue'], resolve)});` whether I use the component or not.

Answer (score 1):

My `webpack.mix.js` contained:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        filename: "js/[id].js"
    }
});
```

After removing this I was able to load correctly. This was intended to move the outputted chunk files to the `js/` directory, but was apparently wrong.